# Simplest way to convert polar coordinates to Cartesian points

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-transformation, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I need to convert polar coordinates from decimal degrees to Cartesian points.
I know there are many formulas but I need a formula that uses only sine and cosine (no arcsine, arccosine), and that does not involve too many calculations.

The coordinates are all within a radius of 150km so it does not matter that it is not precise with coordinates far from each other.

Thanks!

Comment: None of the formulas should include inverse sines or cosines unless you are estimating polar from cartesian.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / trigonometry / coordinate systems / mathematics instead of directly about programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have 2D polar coordinates with angle `theta` and radius `r`, then:

```
x = r * cos(theta)
y = r * sin(theta)
```